# How to update nautilus bookmarks after changing user-dirs?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gtk, desktop-environments, xdg

I change the user-dirs.dirs of xdg.

However, those changed dirs like the Pictures bookmarks are missing, how to make the bookmarks shown again?

Thanks.